# Прием бинарных данных от клиента при помощи socket.io(Python)

Tags: python, socket.io

Вопрос состоит в следующем: есть клиент(устройство), которое шлет бинарные данные на сервер. Сервер работает на Python с использованием socket.io. При получении данных в консоли появляется ошибка:

```
 code 400, message Bad request syntax ('ÿ%\x03\x00')
```

Как задать кодировку для socket.io, чтобы принять данные и обработать их. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какая версия socket.io? Помню была у них там открытая проблема по поводу кодировок

Comment: python-socketio==5.5.2